# node.js powered by C libxml & libxslt

Tags: c, xml, node.js, xslt

Unfortunately I'm neither able to write C-code nor to implement available (and proven) libraries like the common libxml and libxslt used by PHP. I wonder if it is so hart to implement them in node.js? As far as I know C libraries could (easily) be implemented for a usage in node.js.

I'm looking forward to see something like this http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp on the server's JS.

I'd love to contribute and migrate / implement these two libs into node. Does anyone know how to do this or is there a quick link explaining this? Remember I've never worked with C, but I'm a PHP-, Java- and JS-developer for about 8 years now.

Maybe someone wants to join me and realize this.

Comment: [node_xslt](https://github.com/bahblah/node_xslt). [xjst](https://github.com/veged/xjst) inspired by xslt. [node_xslt](https://github.com/bahblah/node_xslt/blob/master/node_xslt.cc#L5) already uses libxslt. Try using that

Comment: Do you want to implement an entire XML parser / XSLT engine in node (good luck with that) or just bind to existing libraries?

Comment: Of course binding to existing libraries to be update-safe and profit from innovations! I wasn't going to reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [node_xslt source code](https://github.com/bahblah/node_xslt/blob/master/node_xslt.cc#L3). You can see it's already interacting with libxslt.

So either use that module, or draw inspiration from it and improve it.

For future reference I used the [npm search registry](http://search.npmjs.org/) and searched for "xslt"

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much raynos. I couldn't search the npm because I'm currently running on win and there are still a few issues with npm.

Comment: @kernel you can still search. It's a website ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this library provides only synchronous methods. You'll want to load that task off to a child process.